# Is it possible to simplify the convolution integral if the functions are non-zero in disjoint areas?

Tags: image-processing, continuous-signals, convolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When convolving two functions that are constants in a region and 0 everywhere else, where does the integration start?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/when-convolving-two-functions-that-are-constants-in-a-region-and-0-everywhere-el)

I have a function $f(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)$.  $f(x,y)$ has a value of $\frac{1}{3}$ when $x$ is between $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{5}{9}$, and $y$ is between $0$ and $1$.  The function has a value of $0$ everywhere else.  Meanwhile, $h(x,y)$ has a value of 1 when both $x$ and $y$ are between $-\frac{1}{19}$ and $\frac{1}{19}$.

These two functions are non-zero in completely disjoint regions.  Is there a way to leverage this property to simplify the convolution integral?

Comment: The short answer is yes, as you can use the regions where you know the signal is zero to constrain the limits on the convolution integral. Instead of integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, you can set the limits such that they only cover the regions where the two functions overlap as you slide them across one another.

Comment: In the other case, the function $f(x,y)$ has value $\frac{1}{3}$ for $|x| < 0.5, 0 < y < 0.4$ and $h(x,y)$ has value $1$ for $-\frac{1}{50} \leq x,y\leq \frac{1}{50}$. Are the questions really all that different? Moderators: please merge the questions.

Answer (score 3):

Link to the closed-form solution:

[wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Convolve[Piecewise[%7B%7B1%2F3%2C+1%2F3+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+5%2F9+%26%26+0+%3C%3D+y+%3C%3D+1%7D%7D]%2C+++Piecewise[%7B%7B1%2C+-1%2F19+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+1%2F19+%26%26+-1%2F19+%3C%3D+y+%3C%3D+1%2F19%7D%7D]%2C+%7Bx%2C++++y%7D%2C+%7Bu%2C+v%7D])

[image]

From left to right: $f$, $h$, and $f*h$:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  This isn't explaining my question really..

Comment: I thought you might be interested in a closed form solution since the question had explicit values for f, h and the boundaries. If that is completely irrelevant, let me know and I'll just delete my answer.

Comment: Maybe a plot of the result would help illustrate it.

Comment: @JasonR Thanks, I have added 3D plots.